# c bit operation bug

Tags: c, macos, gcc, bit

The source of x updated. It is an assignment and I am asked to fill the function. The assignment's requirement is that I cannot change the argument type or do any type casting. So I have this question.

I want to implement bit count use c. Here is the code:

```
int bitCount(int x) {
    int mask1 = 0x55555555;
    int mask2 = 0x33333333;
    int mask3 = 0x0f0f0f0f;
    int mask4 = 0x00ff00ff;
    int mask5 = 0x0000ffff;
    //x = 0xffffffff;
    if (x != 0xffffffff) {
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("%x\n", x);
    x = (x & mask1) + ((x >> 1) & mask1);
    printf("%x\n", x);
    x = (x & mask2) + ((x >> 2) & mask2);
    printf("%x\n", x);
    x = (x & mask3) + ((x >> 4) & mask3);
    printf("%x\n", x);
    x = (x & mask4) + ((x >> 8) & mask4);
    printf("%x\n", x);
    x = (x & mask5) + ((x >> 16) & mask5);
    printf("%x\n", x);

    return x;
}
```

When `x` = -1 (or `0xffffffff` in hex), the answer should be `0x20`. But actually the output is:

```
ffffffff
aaaaaaaa
24444444
6080808
e0010
1e
```

If I uncomment the line 
`"x = 0xffffffff"` in the code, the output becomes:

```
ffffffff
aaaaaaaa
44444444
8080808
100010
20
```

The OS is Mac OS X. gcc version is:

```
gcc --version
```

Configured with:

```
--prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Why?

Comment: Where does `x` actually come from?

Comment: Also, the version string makes it quite clear that this is in fact not gcc, but clang. I assume OSX aliases clang to gcc.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @PaulR of course there is no minimal, complete and verifiable example, as this is UB :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: OK, well I'd settle for minimal and complete. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, right shift of negative integers is implementation-defined:

> The result of `E1 >> E2` is
>   `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions.  If `E1` has an unsigned type or if `E1` has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral
>   part  of  the  quotient  of `E1 / 2^E2`. If E1 has  a  signed  type  and  a  negative  value,  the resulting value is implementation-defined.

However, let's assume we're using x86, and right shift of negative integers there works exactly as if it was 2's complement representation, and results in a proper 32-bit value. If `int x = 0xFFFFFFFF` then `x & mask1` is `0x55555555` and `(x >> 1) & mask` is also `0x55555555`, both of which are positive; and their sum is `0xAAAAAAAA` then

```
x = (x & mask1) + ((x >> 1) & mask1);
```

causes a **signed integer overflow** if `int` is 32-bit wide, thus your code has **undefined behaviour**. You <s>should</s> must use `unsigned int` for such bit twiddling instead of `int`.

I cannot reproduce your bug on my computer, but I can get the same output by masking the sign bit out of `x` after the overflowing addition:

```
x = (x & mask1) + ((x >> 1) & mask1);
x = x & 0x7FFFFFFF;
```

Only with this change I manage to get the incorrect output that you're observing:

```
ffffffff
aaaaaaaa
24444444
6080808
e0010
1e
```

---

This undefined behaviour with 32-bit integers has increased a lot when the 64-bit processors have become more commonplace - according to C standard the compiler is allowed to use a 64-bit register for 32-bit **signed** integers, because *they never overflow* and if you do overflow them, your "32-bit" `int` variable can even end up containing a **64-bit value**.

Answer (score 1):

I was about to go to bed, but then I was bothered by this answer, so I got up.  I don't thing it's about initialization / not initializing.  It is hard to know because your code is only 1/2 there, but I think it is more about signed / unsigned differences.

You are shifting right, which for signed numbers preserves the negative bits; but for unsigned will not.  It looks like your number sets that have smaller values are the result of using unsigned numbers in your shifts.

I noticed that you didn't specify the type of `x`.  That's really odd for `C` and you really should put a type in front of that variable.

--- Original post follows ---

In the

```
x = 0xffffffff;
```

You clearly intialize your variable `x` to a known specific value.

in the

```
if (x != 0xffffffff) {
```

you clearly check whatever is in your uninitialized variable `x` against a known specific value.  In short, you have no idea what was in the ram for variable `x` prior to the run of your program, and that is what you are going to be reading.

You just "got lucky" and had some output that "sort of looked right", but if you ran it in a different manner, or on a different machine, odds are you wouldn't get the same output at all.

Comment: While that may or may not be true (we don't know where `x` comes from and thus neither if it is initialized or not), I don't see that it answers the question at all. The first `printf` also confirms that `x` is indeed `0xffffffff`, no?

Comment: @Dolda2000 You are right, but I'm not even sure `x` is an `int` in the second case.  I updated the post.  I think it has to do with the lack of type and how the type is getting inferred differently in the two cases.  Basically in one case it seems to be unsigned while the other case is signed.

Comment: Yes, I have similar suspicions, but it is indeed hard to tell without knowing what `x` is. Then again, assigning to `x` shouldn't change its type, and also the masks should remove any extended sign bits making `signed`/`unsigned` distinctions irrelevant.

Comment: Right-shifting negative numbers is actually implementation dependant

Comment: signed integer overflow